# How to run insert and delete combined with sed regexp?

Tags: sed

I have a file like this:

```
   <?php $unused.. ?><?php
```

.. content varies.

I need to remove that line and insert `<?php` to the start.
I've been trying with following, but line doesn't get inserted in the output.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
sed '/<\?php $unused/d;1s/^/<\?php \n/' testfile
```

Comment: If "<?php $unused.." is in the first line, then 1s ... won't execute, since the flow is already changed to second line (although it's the new 1st line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert `<?php` then delete `<?php $unused` :

```
sed '1i \
<?php
/<\?php \$unused/d;' testfile
```